# Determine if Sprite Rotated 360 Degrees - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, rotation

I have a sprite that rotates with touch.  I need to be able to determine if it has rotated 360 degrees 3 times. Is there any way to tell?

Here is what I have so far

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameScene.h"



@interface G : CCLayer {

    CCSprite *g;

    CGFloat gRotation;
}

@end

------------------------------------------
#import "G.h"


@implementation G

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

        g = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"g.png"];

        [self addChild:g z:-1];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)update:(ccTime)delta
{
    g.rotation = gRotation;
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint firstLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    CGPoint touchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    CGPoint firstTouchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:firstLocation];

    CGPoint firstVector = ccpSub(firstTouchingPoint, g.position);
    CGFloat firstRotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(firstVector);
    CGFloat previousTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(firstRotateAngle);

    CGPoint vector = ccpSub(touchingPoint, g.position);
    CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(vector);
    CGFloat currentTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotateAngle);

    gRotation += currentTouch - previousTouch;
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (void) dealloc
{
    CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

GameScene

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import "MainMenu.h"
#import "G.h"


@implementation GameScene

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    GameScene *layer = [GameScene node];

    [scene addChild: layer];
    return scene;
}

-(void) tapG: (id) sender
{

    G *gView;
    gView = [[G alloc] init];
    gView.position = ccp(100, 100);

    [self.parent addChild:gView z:1001];

    [gView scheduleUpdate];

    [gView release];
}
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
tG = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"tp.png" selectedImage:@"tp.png"  disabledImage:@"tpaperd.png" target:self selector:@selector(tapG:)];

        gt = [CCMenu menuWithItems:tG, nil];
        gt.position = ccp(210, 80);
        [gt alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:10];

        [self addChild:gt z:0];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void) dealloc
    {
        CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

        [super dealloc];
    }
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify the following: 1) does the graphics library you're working with track rotational values greater than 360? 2) Does the direction of rotation matter?  That is, if it rotates 360 left, then 360 right then 360 left, is that considered 3 full rotations?

Comment: 1)I forgot to mention I'm using Cocos2d(I'm not sure if it does, but I set a log for if(grotation > 361) { CCLOG(@"passed 360"); } and it was never called so I don't think it tracks values greater than 360) 2)Yes, that is exactly what I need. 360 left, 360 right, 360 left again is 3 full rotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cocos2d can take rotations more than 360. but if your going left and right then its a bit more complicated than just checking if `sprite.rotation == 1080`. if the rotation is happening on your `touchesMoved` method then what you should do is that you should record your highest rotation (rotation in right maybe) and lowest rotation (the other way) and then the difference should be bigger than 360*3. so add 2 class vars to your G layer `float maxRot,minRot;`

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    maxRot = mySprite.rotation; // here you set the ivars to defaults. 
    minRot = mySprite.rotation; // im setting them to your sprite initial rotation
}                               // incase it is not 0
```

at the end of your `touchesMoved` method you check for your conditions:

```
if (mySprite.rotation > maxRot)
   maxRot = mySprite.rotation;

else if (mysprite.rotation < minRot)
   minRot = mySprite.rotation;

if ((maxRot - minRot) >= (360*3)) {

    // your condition is satisfied
}
```

i havent tested this so it could be just wrong.. but its worth a shot

### EDIT:

the code above will not work unless the rotations are happening in the same direction.. it wont work for your right, left, right condition. I guess one way is to track the direction of your rotation in `touchesMoved`. so again youll need class vars

```
int numOfRots;
float previousRot, currentRot, accumRot;
BOOL isPositive, isPreviousPositive;
```

your touches methods:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    previousRot = mySprite.rotation; 
    currentRot = mySprite.rotation;
    accumRot = 0;
    numOfRots = 0;
    isPositive = NO;
    isPreviousPositive = NO;
}
```

at the end of `touchesMoved` you will have the following:

```
currentRot = mySprite.rotation;

if (currentRot > previousRot)
    isPositive = YES;
else
    isPositive = NO;

if (isPositive != isPreviousPositive) {

    // now we have a change in direction, reset the vars
    accumRot = 0;
}

if (isPositive) {

   accumRot += abs(currentRot - previousRot);
}

else {

   accumRot += abs(previousRot - currentRot); 
}


if (accumRot >= 360) {

    //now we have one rotation in any direction.
    numOfRots++;        
    //need to reset accumRot to check for another rot
    accumRot = 0;


    if (numOfRots == 3) {

        //BINGO!!! now you have 3 full rotations
    }
}

previousRot = currentRot;
isPreviousPositive = isPositive;
```

hope this helps

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Thank you so much! You just helped me finish my first game!